# How do I use "Jupyter Lab" to run the streamlit web app?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, streamlit

As I know the command "**streamlit run  my_app_name.py**" is needed to run streamlit application. but in jupyter lab, how can I do that?  other applications (like dash or flask) working nicely on **jupyter lab**. Is there any way to run on here python streamlit application?

Comment: You can't run it from within a jupyter notebook, streamlit starts a server on the main thread

Comment: Thanks, but I am talking about ** jupyter lab** as I am running flask and dash application on jupyter lab.

Comment: If you are actually using JupyterHub in conjunction with your JupyterLab, you may want to see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/streamlit-app-and-binder/9487/4?u=fomightez). Or see about the `http-server proxy`also talked about there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run streamlit on jupyter lab but you can use the conda env to run streamlit

Activate the env and run streamlit on cmd/terminal

[image: 1]